# Fast and elegant way to perform operation on 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, loops, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have the following data:

- `img`: a 3D numpy array representing a hyperspectral image of shape (200, 200, 256), i.e. 200x200 pixels each of which holds 256 integer reflectance values at evenly-spaced wavelengths (bands)
- `reference_spectrum`: a numpy array which holds 256 integer reflectance values (like a single pixel)
- `dist`: a distance function that takes two numpy arrays of the same length and returns a real number

I would like to obtain a 2D numpy array `result` of shape (200, 200) such that `result[i, j] == dist(img[i, j], reference_spectrum)`.

First I wrote the obvious nested for loop:

```
result = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        result[i, j] = dist(img[r, c], reference_spectrum)
```

This is slow and looks ugly.

Then I used the distance function $dist(a, b) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} |a_i-b_i|$ and I wrote the following code:

```
temp = np.zeros(img.shape)
for k in range(img.shape[2]):
    temp[: , :, k] = abs(img[: , :, k] - reference_spectrum[k])
result = np.sum(temp, axis=2)
```

This is faster but only works with a specific distance function.

I'm looking for a fast and modular (w.r.t. the distance function) solution.

Comment: so `dist` only works with 1d arrays, the `img[i,j,:]` and `ref`?  If you can't generalize it to work with 2d (or 3d) `img` slice, you can't avoid the loops.

Comment: Yes, ```dist``` in my case only makes sense on 1d arrays.

Comment: Simplify the special case to `np.abs(img- reference_spectrum).sum(axis=2)`.  (n,n,256) broadcasts with (256,)

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the dim of your ref, and apply the operations on the last dim. For example, let suppose you want `mse` error:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(200, 200, 256)
ref = np.random.randn(256)

# mse = np.mean(error**2)
error = (data - ref.reshape(1, 1, -1))
mse = np.mean(error**2, axis=-1)
print(mse.shape)
```

There is also `numpy.apply_along_axis`, which provide the possibility to apply func along one axis

Comment: `apply` isn't faster.